# Need some assistance with my logic in cloning an object

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, compareto, cloneable

Before I posted this, I read some of the previous posts and I really don't see anything wrong with my logic. (I'm 3 hours on this already and it's probably gonna kill my happy hour) ****I never want to know the answers, I enjoy working hard so maybe if anyone can maybe ask me a question as to what I am trying to achieve that can lead me to think of the answer using your clues or hints. It will be appreciated.**** obj2 is not cloning so behind the exception stackTrace, I found that there is a nullpointer exception on the same line which means that obj2 is never getting cloned. Please help me to think a little harder.

```
package testbankaccount;

/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
public interface Cloneable {

}
```

My parent class

```
package testbankaccount;

/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
public abstract class BankAccount implements Cloneable, Comparable {
    private double balance; 
    private int numberofDeposits; 
    private int numberofWithdrawals; 
    private double annualInterestRate; 
    private double monthlyServiceCharges; 
    private String customerName;



protected BankAccount(){
    this(1.0, 1.0);
}

protected BankAccount(double balance, double annualInterestRate){
    this.balance = balance;
    this.annualInterestRate = annualInterestRate;
}

public void deposit(double deposit){
    balance += deposit;
    numberofDeposits++; 
}

public void withdraw(double withdrawal){
    balance -= withdrawal;
    numberofWithdrawals++;
}

public void calcInterest(){
    double monthlyInterestRate = annualInterestRate/1200;
    double monthlyInterest = balance * monthlyInterestRate;
    balance += monthlyInterest; 
}

public void setMonthlyServiceCharge(double serviceCharge){
    monthlyServiceCharges = serviceCharge;
}

public void monthlyProcess(){
    balance -= monthlyServiceCharges;
    calcInterest();
    numberofWithdrawals = 0;
    numberofDeposits = 0;
    monthlyServiceCharges = 0.0;
}
public void setBalance(double balance){
     this.balance = balance;
}

public double getBalance(){
    return balance;
}

public int getNumberWithdraws(){
    return numberofWithdrawals;
}

@Override
    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {

        return super.clone();

      }



    @Override
public abstract String toString();

    @Override
public abstract boolean equals(Object obj);

}
```

My subclass

```
package testbankaccount;

/**
 *
 * @author Darren Wright
 */
public class SavingsAccount extends BankAccount implements Cloneable, Comparable {

private boolean status;


public SavingsAccount(){
    this(1.0,1.0);
}

public SavingsAccount(double balance, double annualInterestRate){
    super(balance,annualInterestRate);

}

public void setActivity(){
    if (getBalance() > 25.0)
     status = true;
    else status = false;
}

    @Override
public void withdraw(double withdrawal){
    if (status = true)
    super.withdraw(withdrawal);     
}

@Override
public void deposit(double deposit){
    if (status = false && (deposit + getBalance()) > 25.0)
    {
            status = true;
            super.deposit(deposit);
    }
    else if (status = true)
            super.deposit(deposit);
}

    @Override
public void monthlyProcess(){
        double result = 0.0;
        if(getNumberWithdraws() >4)
        result = getNumberWithdraws() - 4;
        setMonthlyServiceCharge(result);
        setActivity();
}
@Override
    public String toString() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

@Override
    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {

        return super.clone();

      }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return (getBalance() == ((SavingsAccount)obj).getBalance());
    }


  public int compareTo(Object obj) {
    if (getBalance() > ((SavingsAccount)obj).getBalance())
      return 1;
    else if (getBalance() < ((SavingsAccount)obj).getBalance())
      return -1;
    else
      return 0;
  }


}
```

My test class

```
package testbankaccount;

/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
public class TestBankAccount{

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)  throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        SavingsAccount obj1 = new SavingsAccount(500,8.25); 
        try{
            SavingsAccount obj2 = (SavingsAccount)obj1.clone();
            System.out.println(obj1.compareTo(obj2));
            System.out.println(obj1.equals(obj2));
         }
         catch (CloneNotSupportedException ex) {
             ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

My error output

```
java.lang.CloneNotSupportedException: testbankaccount.SavingsAccount
    at java.lang.Object.clone(Native Method)
    at testbankaccount.BankAccount.clone(BankAccount.java:69)
    at testbankaccount.SavingsAccount.clone(SavingsAccount.java:60)
    at testbankaccount.TestBankAccount.main(TestBankAccount.java:16)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

What am I missing in my thought process? I created the interface, I implemented it and overided it in my super and subclass. My subclass refers super.clone() to the superclass and the super.clone() in the superclass I'm thinking refers to the Object's clone method. I casted correctly in the test class but obj2 winds up being null in both the compareTo and of course the equals. What am I not thinking about?

Comment: Why are you creating your own Cloneable interface rather than use the one that's part of the Java core library?

Comment: implements java.lang.Cloneable rather testbankaccount.Cloneable which you have created.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't be creating your own `Cloneable` interface.  You should use the [one that's built-in](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html).

Comment: +1. An alternative is to declare `implements java.lang.Cloneable` (using the fully qualified interface name).

Comment: @Ted True. If he really had a reason why he wanted to create his own interface and the name match was just a coincidence, this would make it work. But in this case, it looks like he has no reason to create such an interface.

Comment: Yep. That was it. When I read from the book about how Cloneable was defined, I mistook that as how it supposed to be implemented. That's a case where I'm reading but not fully absorbing. Thanks everyone. Sorry to have wasted your time.

Answer (score 1):

Don't create your own public interface Cloneable. Now you're getting the one you defined rather than the system one. So instead of implementing the "real" Cloneable, you're implementing your own, which the Object.clone function then does not recognize as making the object cloneable.

You'll also need to write a public clone function for each class that you want to be able to clone, to override the protection from private to public.

Java makes it a major pain to make an object cloneable, for reasons that I don't understand.